# How to add text before and after exploding the string

Tags: php, mysql

hi i am fetching some data from MySQL for  example

```
    <ol>
       <li></li> 
       <li></li> 
       <li></li> 
      </ol>
  explode('<li>', $data );
```

i explode the the string after `<li>` now i want to add certain value before the first array and after the last array how to achieve this

the current result is

```
 hi

 hi1

 hi2
```

i want result like

- hi *
- hi1 *
- hi2 *

Comment: Welcome to the site! You need to provide more information. What is your desired result? What have you tried?

Comment: Are you saying you want to add one value into the first position of an array and one to the last?

Comment: What are you effectively trying to achieve? Some HTML transformation? Be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below code :

```
$str = 'hi
hi1
hi2';
$array = explode(' ', $str);
foreach ($array as $arr)
{
   echo "<li>$arr *</li>";  
}
```